# Word-sized OUT to a byte IO register? Setting the Sequence Controller Register with out instructions in old VGA code

Tags: assembly, x86, vga, ioports

I'm having trouble understanding how the Sequence Controller Registers are set in this example with some old VGA code:

```
 mov     dx,SC_INDEX
 mov     ax,0604h
 out     dx,ax   ;disable chain4 mode
```

The example is from Michael Abrash's VGA book: https://www.phatcode.net/res/224/files/html/ch47/47-02.html

According to the description he wants to set the Memory Mode register which is at Index 4. He wants to disable chain4 which is at Bit Index 3 (all according to the Programmer's Guide to the EGA, VGA and Super VGA Cards by Richard F. Ferraro).

I fail to understand why he puts 2 bytes 06 and 04 into ax and `out`'s them. The out register is only one byte and he doesn't explicitly set the index of the register for addressing. Is there some magic happening that I don't understand?

Comment: *The out and register* - Is that broken grammar, or is there a "VGA and register" that you're talking about? (I think https://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware#Read.2FWrite_logic)?  If so, I'd suggest "VGA `and` register".  Or "VGA write mode" register', unless that would imply the whole 2-byte pair of IO registers.

Comment: This was just bad grammar in the question, sorry. I corrected it.

Answer (score 5):

The I/O ports are 8-bit, but 2/4 consecutive ports can also be treated as a single 16/32-bit port - that `out` instruction will write to both `SC_INDEX` and `SC_INDEX+1`.

You can check eg. the Intel 80386 Reference Programmer's Manual's section on [I/O addressing](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2004/readings/i386/s08_01.htm) for the port width thing, and osdev.org even seems to mention the practice specifically [when discussing that specific port](https://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware#Port_0x3C4.2C_0x3CE.2C_0x3D4).

Comment: Note that this “treating consecutive ports as a 16/32 bit port” is possible on modern machines, but it may not be possible on some early AT motherboards as they did not split 16 bit accesses to 8 bit ports.

Comment: I see, this makes more sense now. Thanks. Since x86 is little endian the 04h in 0604h goes to SC_INDEX and indeed selects Memory Mode register at 4. 06h disables bit 3 and enables some others (have to figure out what this doing).